# Covariance and Contravariance conversion fails

Tags: c#, covariance, contravariance

I know I'm missing something, but shouldn't this work!?

```
public interface IFoo<out TA, in TB>
    where TA : class
    where TB : class
{
}
public class Foo<T> : IFoo<T, T> where T : class { }
public class Whatever { }
```

...

```
Foo<Whatever> _Foo = new Foo<Whatever>(); // (changed "Foo" to "_Foo to be more clear)
var f = (IFoo<object, object>)_Foo; // CAST ERROR
```

FYI: The original project is .NET 4.0 using VS 2013.

**Edit:**  It appears that an 'in' type for the 'TB' parameter (contravariance) must be either the SAME type, or a DERIVED type.  Since 'object' is a supertype (as in, 'object' does not derive from type 'Whatever'), the conversion fails. (thanks to Aasmund Eldhuset)

This does work:

```
public class WhateverB : Whatever { }
var f = (IFoo<object, WhateverB>)Foo; // YAY ;)
```

Comment: Your code does not compile.  Do you have a variable named `Foo`?  If so what is its type?

Comment: But an interface cannot be both covariant and contravariant on the same type.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `var f = (IFoo<object, object>)Foo;` here, `Foo` appears to be used as if it were a variable or property, can you show how it is declared?

Comment: The only way this cast can work is if `Foo` is an instance of `Foo<object>`. If you have the same type parameter in a covariant and contravariant position then it is invariant.

Comment: Sorry, I added a missing line.  This code does compile, but errors out at runtime.

Comment: @DStanley: You may be able to pull off a covariant and contravariant parameter of the same type using this kind of trick, but it would be equivalent to a normal generic (as nothing can be both a super and sub class of a class but that class itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Foo<string>` is *not* an `IFoo<object, object>`, because the generic type parameter `TB` doesn't match - for an `in` generic type parameter, the actual type must be equal to or be a superclass of the generic type parameter, but `string` is not a superclass of `object`.

The reason the cast is accepted by the compiler is that a cast to an interface type is *almost always* legal (except in the corner case that PetSerAl mentions), because it could be that some subclass of the type you're casting from implements the interface.

Comment: `cast to an interface type is always legal` How about cast from sealed class to not implemented interface?

Comment: Sorry, I put in string by mistake thinking it acted like a class.  In fact, it doesn't matter, as using a proper class still doesn't work.  Take another look.

Comment: So you are saying that Foo<string> does not equal IFoo<string,string>?  That doesn't even make sense. IFoo<string,string> should equal IFoo<object,object>.

Comment: @JamesWilkins - `IFoo<string, string>` is not convertible to an `IFoo<object, object>` since `TB` is contravariant.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I see what you mean.  I didn't read carefully enough.  The "in" type must be a SUPERclass, got it.  I read the MSDN article, but as usual, it's useless (info missing).

Comment: Making TB type 'Whatever' in the conversion makes it work, so yes, you're right. ;) Thanks.